# Consulta igualando con los valores de un arreglo

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs

Tengo un *array* de `ids` permitidos:

```
array=[90,18,7,1];
objBD.query(' SELECT *' + 'from USUARIO c\n' + 'where c.TIPO=\'registro\' and (c.id==array[i])', function (err, rows) {
    return done(null, rows);
});
```

No sé como incorporarlos dinámicamente en mi consulta.

¿Debo ponerlos en un `for`?

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor indicar en qué lenguaje de programación estás trabajando? Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy usando javascipt

Comment: ¿Javascript? Imposible, con JS no puedes consultar a la BD, la cual estaría en el servidor, mientras que JS está del lado del cliente.

Comment: @A.Cedano nodejs uso el framework expressjs

Comment: @A.Cedano uso js en el lado del servidor

Comment: No conozco `Node`, pero sería cuestión de crear una lista con los valores del array y pasarlo con la consulta escrita de este modo: `SELECT * from USUARIO  where  c.TIPO=\'registro\' and c.id IN (***aquí lista de ids***)`, en JS por ejemplo puedes convertir un array a lista usando `join`. Sería cuestión de usar la función que hace eso mismo en `Node`. En JS para listar el array separado por comas sería algo como `array.join()` y la consulta quedaría así: `SELECT * from USUARIO  where  c.TIPO=\'registro\' and c.id IN (array.join)`

Comment: @A.Cedano si esta bien, puedes publicar tu respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Dado que MySQL cuenta con el [operador de comparación **`IN`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), que acepta como parámetro una lista de criterios, puedes crear una lista separadas por comas a partir del array y pasarla en con `IN` en la consulta.

La consulta quedaría entonces así:

```
SELECT * from USUARIO where c.TIPO=\'registro\' and c.id IN (array.join)
```